# Why do I get "the method exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied" when extending Result for failure types?

Tags: error-handling, rust, traits

I'm trying to add a more concise version of the `failure` crate's `.with_context(|e| format!("foo: {}", e))` to my code. Like this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b7b34d27fa949cae0e7d1991d3c784b4):

```rust
use failure::{Context, Fail, ResultExt}; // 0.1.5

/// Extension methods for failure `Result`.
pub trait ResultContext<T, E> {
    /// Wraps the error type in a context type generated by looking at the
    /// error value. This is very similar to `with_context` but much more
    /// concise.
    fn ctx(self, s: &str) -> Result<T, Context<String>>;
}

impl<T, E> ResultContext<T, E> for Result<T, E>
where
    E: Fail,
{
    fn ctx(self, s: &str) -> Result<T, Context<String>> {
        self.map_err(|failure| {
            let context = format!("{}: {}", s, failure);
            failure.context(context)
        })
    }
}

pub fn foo() -> Result<i32, failure::Error> {
    Ok(5i32)
}

pub fn main() -> Result<(), failure::Error> {
    // This works.
    let _ = foo().with_context(|_| "foo".to_string())?;
    // This doesn't.
    foo().ctx("foo")?
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `ctx` found for type `std::result::Result<i32, failure::error::Error>` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:31:11
   |
31 |     foo().ctx("foo")?
   |           ^^^
   |
   = note: the method `ctx` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
           `std::result::Result<i32, failure::error::Error> : ResultContext<_, _>`
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is implemented and in scope
   = note: the following trait defines an item `ctx`, perhaps you need to implement it:
           candidate #1: `ResultContext`
```

I can't work out why. I more or less copied the existing `with_context` code.

Comment: [`context`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/failure/trait.ResultExt.html#tymethod.context) does already what you want

Comment: Ah good point, still for the purposes of education (and suppose I think `context` is too verbose), any idea why my code fails?

Comment: I'll take the opportunity to promote my own error crate, [SNAFU](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.4.1/snafu/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the compiler tells you, `Result<i32, failure::error::Error>` doesn't implement `ResultContext<_, _>`. You have added a bound to your implementation:

```
where
    E: Fail,
```

But **`failure::Error` doesn't implement `failure::Fail`**:

```
use failure; // 0.1.5

fn is_fail<F: failure::Fail>() {}

pub fn main() {
    is_fail::<failure::Error>();
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `failure::error::Error: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     is_fail::<failure::Error>();
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `failure::error::Error`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `failure::Fail` for `failure::error::Error`
note: required by `is_fail`
 --> src/main.rs:3:1
  |
3 | fn is_fail<F: failure::Fail>() {}
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You will need to alter your bounds or your type.

Comment: Ahhhh I totally missed that it worked with `with_context()` and so on because there is *also* [an implementation of `ResultExt` for `Result<T, Error>`](https://docs.rs/failure/0.1.5/src/failure/result_ext.rs.html#182-202). Thanks.

Comment: Also I feel like the error message could definitely be improved!