# Use object guarded by Mutex

Tags: rust, static, mutex, lazy-initialization

I want to implement a lazy static [reqwest::ClientBuilder](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html). NB this is for a utilities module, so I have a feeling it'd be difficult to avoid using a static in this case. I want to construct it once, and then use it for building possibly several `reqwest::Client`s (for different timeouts, which are set on construction of the client).

So I have this line (using `once_cell::sync::Lazy`):

```
static CLIENT_BUILDER: Lazy<Mutex<Option<ClientBuilder>>> = Lazy::new(|| Mutex::new(None));
```

Then I have this function:

```
pub fn get_reqwest_client(timeout: u64 = 5_000) -> Result<Client, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut client_builder_guard = CLIENT_BUILDER.lock().unwrap();
    let client_builder = match client_builder_guard.as_ref() {
        Some(client_builder) => client_builder,
        None => {
            // configuration of builder
            let es_path = r#"D:\apps\ElasticSearch\elasticsearch-8.6.2\config"#;
            set_var("ES_PATH_CONF", &es_path); // from crate tmp_env
            let mut buf = Vec::new();
            let cert_path = format!(r#"{es_path}\certs\http_ca.crt"#);
            let mut cert_file = File::open(cert_path).expect("problem opening certificate file");
            let _ = cert_file.read_to_end(&mut buf);
            let cert = reqwest::Certificate::from_pem(&buf).expect("problem generating certificate");
            let client_builder = Client::builder()
                .add_root_certificate(cert);
            // setting the Lazy Mutex
            *client_builder_guard = Some(client_builder);
            client_builder_guard.as_ref().unwrap()
        }
    };
    ...
```

Then a bit later in that function:

```
let client = client_builder.as_ref()
    .timeout(std::time::Duration::from_millis(timeout))
    .build()?;
```

This gives an error:

```
error[E0599]: the method `as_ref` exists for reference `&ClientBuilder`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> D:\My documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\doc_indexer\src\core\utilities\src\lib.rs:154:35
    |
154 |             let client = client_builder.as_ref()
    |                                         ^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `&ClientBuilder` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
   ::: D:\apps\rust\rust_1.70.0\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\reqwest-0.11.20\src\blocking\client.rs:69:1
    |
69  | pub struct ClientBuilder {
    | ------------------------ doesn't satisfy `reqwest::blocking::ClientBuilder: AsRef<_>`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `reqwest::blocking::ClientBuilder: AsRef<_>`
            which is required by `&reqwest::blocking::ClientBuilder: AsRef<_>`
```

I've also tried `*client_builder` and `client_builder.clone();` and even `client_builder_guard.as_ref().unwrap()`. Nothing seems to work.

Why is the `Copy` trait involved in this and is there a solution? I've reread the compiler messaging and don't understand (I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56582508/595305) for example, but on the face of it it doesn't seem to be applicable).

**Edit in response to comment**
If I just omit `as_ref()` in the above (which I had tried) I get:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*client_builder` which is behind a shared reference
   --> D:\My documents\software projects\EclipseWorkspace\doc_indexer\src\core\utilities\src\lib.rs:153:20
    |
153 |               let client = client_builder
    |  __________________________^
154 | |                 .timeout(std::time::Duration::from_millis(timeout))
    | |___________________________________________________________________^ move occurs because `*client_builder` has type `reqwest::blocking::ClientBuilder`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `.as_ref()`? That is a method on `Option`, and you already handle the option being `None` using `match`. Honestly this looks like an xy problem - could you post the simplest version of the code that you'd like to write, so we can see what went wrong at the beginning?

Comment: Thanks. See update. I don't know what you mean about simplest version or "at the beginning".

Comment: Why not initialize the `ClientBuilder` inside of the `Lazy`, instead of trying to do it manually and have having the lazy just construct the Mutex? Someone with 14k rep ought to know to post an MCVE.

Comment: By "in the beginning" I meant that you probably inserted `as_ref()` to fix an issue. You should show us that issue (as you now did). It would also be nice if you provided a totally minimal version of that function that still demonstrates the problem, to make it easier to help you.

Comment: The underlying issue here is that you cannot reuse a `ClientBuilder` singleton to create multiple clients - that kind of thing is explicitly prohibited by the [signature of build()](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html#method.build), which consumes `self`. You need to rethink your strategy.

Comment: @user4815162342 Ahhhhh, consumes `self`, got it. Thanks. As a newb I don't know whether the compiler might perhaps be hoped to point more usefully in such a direction in a case like this. But I'll examine parameters even more carefully in future!

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I'm even more surprised that someone with a 24k rep should pretend not to be aware that sometimes questioners include an MRE and sometimes they don't. There was no special or imperious need for that here and it just needed someone with sufficient expertise to spot the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm well aware that some questions don't include a MRE. Most of the times (like, 95%) they should. And _we as the answerers_ should decide that, not _you as the asker_ (which by definition, don't know what the answer will be). You should put all effort you can into your question. It's the minimum request from someone who wants to get help for free.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I put much effort into this question, after trying for more than an hour to solve the problem on my own. People who are kind enough to choose to help can indeed request an MRE if they feel the questioner is wrong not to have supplied one, but if so perhaps they should do so with rudimentary courtesy, not with a snidey "ooh, you've got a 14k rep but you're too stupid/lazy to have provided an MRE". Incidentally, I just looked at your last 10 questions and it seems to me that only one has an MRE. Jus' sayin'.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question may help others, not just with `reqwest::ClientBuilder` but possibly also with other "builder" type patterns.

The explanation for the problem pointed out by user4815162342 is that `ClientBuilder.build`'s signature is `pub fn build(self) -> Result<Client>`. It thus consumes the builder, meaning that a new builder is needed for each client. The problems which were caused by trying to create a reusable builder caused the difficult-to-understand compiler messages.

... unfortunately `set_timeout` isn't one of the optional chainable methods available for `reqwest::Client`, so I opted for a static timeout-to-client map and had hoped that having a single builder might speed up the creation of possible multiple clients. This is not possible.

Comment: You can use a function to build the `ClientBuilder`, so it has the same ease-of-use as a static one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write the answer. Don't feel discouraged by the bad experience, keep asking questions. More importantly, have fun with Rust!